# Typescript reference interface own property

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I would like to use the type of a property of an Interface as a generic, but I'm not sure if what I want to do is supported. I'll explain it with code:

Normally we can do this:

```
enum Sections {
  users = 'users',
  projects = 'projects'
}

interface SectionEles {
  [Section.users] : {...};
  [Section.projects]: {...};
}

interface SezViewSettings<S extends Sections> = {
  section: S;
  where: Array<keyof SectionEles[S]>;
}
```

This works fine, but I want to avoid to make `SezViewSettings` a `generic`. I'd prefer to desume `S` from the value assigned to the property `section`, something like this:

```
interface SezViewSettings = {
  section: S extends Sections;
  where: Array<keyof SectionEles[S]>;
}
```

Can this be done?

Comment: You can't do it with an interface.  Instead you could use a union type, like maybe `type SezViewSettingUnion<S extends Section = Section> =  S extends any ? SezViewSettings<S> : never;` and then just use `SezViewSettingUnion`.  Does that work for you?  If not, please clarify your use case.  Also please consider editing the code to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into an IDE and demonstrating your issue and only your issue (so no syntax errors or undeclared types).

Comment: Right! This did it. Is a little verbose but works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interface cannot represent this constraint without generics.

In this case, your possible `S` types are *enumerable*, so you can form a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) of `SezViewSettings<S>` for all possible `S` values and use that as your type.  This may be sufficient for your needs.

Here's one way to do it, by making a [mapped type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) whose properties are immediately [looked up](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types):

```
type SezViewSettingUnion = { [S in Section]: SezViewSettings<S> }[Section]
/* type SezViewSettingUnion = SezViewSettings<Section.users> | 
     SezViewSettings<Section.projects>
*/
```

Similarly, you can use [distributive conditional types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```
type _SezViewSettingUnion<S extends Section> =
    S extends any ? SezViewSettings<S> : never;
type SezViewSettingUnion = _SezViewSettingUnion<Section>;
/* type SezViewSettingUnion = SezViewSettings<Section.users> | 
SezViewSettings<Section.projects> */
```

Both of those end up producing the same type, equivalent to `SezViewSettings<Section.users> | SezViewSettings<Section.projects>`.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!
[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYOwrgtgBAysDGAXAlgexFA3gKCnqYAzsAE6FQC8UA5EaYdQDS74AOJqAVgouVdey48G2AL7ZsyEIlIAzAIbxgsHmhABRADbByOfFADacJGoB0dMgF0AXFijzbARijj9R1elODuSQjbsARrYATC4A3GISUjIkCkoqAF4AasjAAO5wiCggAOaEADwwUMAAHjIgACbkxijoAHxYLHjEJui2MBH6aQAWpMC2AIIkJPIAnvkA1sCjqLIqrRrahEaWdRHi2CDyEDqsisoAsvKsrMAVADKoqBNgrI36iKOniSnpmdk5AKogapR2RlApPNaiB-HBkqkMsAslI8oUGqJ3AtLE0oAB6ABUUEez3BryhMNy31+VDxkPesIKNTMFkIDQAPlBUfoXuToR8qR4QF4OD5eHVURi0ZFNttdvsoAARZCERAkZABMAoABuwAAwugKsgQfJNPd8DjlAB9Mlvdmw4noQrFMqgKrAtQNCjM-BFUrle3yECjKAAflZZsJcJgDVsIGAqpInQNT2UpoJH0tGCoJuAEMDiZ+Vup9WjeEx2NjAYTFqzyeLFNynIW5mIZAZTP08crwa5PKEvgaQpFQA)

Comment: Thanks, this works but ubnfortunately I got the error `Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite`, so I ended up statically typing all cases

Comment: I can't reproduce that error; if you can produce a [mcve] I might be able to advise.  Otherwise, good luck!

Comment: It's a common error that TS throws then types inferring relies on too many recursions, it's not a bug with the code itself. It's really hard to reproduce as the code needs to go very deep to encounter that error, and at that point it's just better to statically declare some types.